# Non-sexist term for girl drinks

Tags: pejorative-language

Is there a non-sexist term for a *[girl drink](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Girl+Drink)* such as a strawberry daiquiri, [banana sunshine](http://www.barmeister.com/drinks/recipe/1950/), or [squashed strawberry alley cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8C4TGGtPzBU)?

I find these drinks delicious, and would like a term to refer them without any sexist connotations.

Comment: Is *mixed drink* suitable, or did you need something more specific, like *fruity drink*?

Comment: There is also the term "frou-frou drinks"

Comment: The idea that there are such things as 'girl drinks' is ineluctably sexist.  How should there be a non-sexist term for a sexist concept ?

Comment: Is differentiating drinks either sex is more apt to drink or at least believed to really sexist though? Wouldn't it be sexist if they were implied to be worse than other drinks, or am I wrong? Girly drinks are delicious drinks. "Manly" drinks are usually sour or bitter or just strongly alcoholic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "fruity" or "sweet" cocktails?

Answer (score 2):

The term **[specialty drinks](http://www.drinkrecipesbar.com/drink-recipes-category-4_Specialty-Drink-Recipes.html)** or **specialty cocktails** is often used for mixed drinks that go beyond the average *gin and tonic*.

When the preparation involves heavy equipment, it is often called a *blended drink*.

Comment: Your last line has me imagining a cement mixer full of alcohol. :)

Comment: @Barmar Some of those blenders make more noise than the cement mixer I operated as a teenager. And the resulting products looked similar.

Answer (score -1):

These drinks are all examples of *cocktails*.

Comment: So are dry martinis and whiskey sours; less often considered "girl drinks" than fruity cocktails are.

Comment: ......hentails?

Comment: Many mixed drinks are cocktails but not girlie drinks.

Comment: Many of the best bartenders understand that a *cocktail* contains bitters, by definition.  To them the examples given are simply *mixed drinks*.